# org-insert-structure-template on non empty line

Tags: org-babel

When I insert a code block, I usually first mark the current line, before I issue org-insert-structure-template, but can I encapsulate the current line, without selecting it?

Something like this, but which works;)

```
(defun org-insert-contextual-structure-template ()
  (interactive)
  (select-current-line)
  (org-insert-structure-template)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but I'm not sure it's worth it. Here's a function to do it:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-wrap-current-line-in-structure-template ()
    (interactive)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (push-mark nil t t)
    (end-of-line)
    (call-interactively #'org-insert-structure-template)
    (pop-mark))
#+end_src
```

It doesn't do a `save-excursion`, so `point` will end up after the `#+begin_src`  so that you can enter the language.

Unfortunately, when `org-insert-structure-template` is to apply to a region, it depends on the region being active (that's what the last `t` argument in the `push-mark` call above does: it makes the mark (and hence the region) active). It would be nicer IMO if it took a region as argument, so that we wouldn't have to resort to using `call-interactively`, but c'est la vie.

Comment: Yet another question, another answer and ... crickets.